# Undo pushed commits of a specific file without affecting commits after that

Tags: git, github, version-control, svm

I have made a commit which I need to undo.

A - B - C - D

I need to undo commit B without affecting commits after it (C and D).

Also there are changes in 2 files (File X and File Y)in commit B. Of which I want to undo change in only one of the file file X .

Note:All these changes are pushed to remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform two steps:

1. Revert the commit
2. Undo the change to the other file(s) from the revert-commit

With Git, you can do it as follows:

```
# on D, i.e. HEAD == D
git revert B # revert the commit
git checkout D -- FileY # restore FileY from commit D
git commit --amend -CHEAD # amend your revert-commit
```

Obviously, the old commit B will be left in the history.

Use `git log -p` or `gitk` (or any other tool of your choice) to verify that the history matches your expectation after those steps.